# Solidity Transaction Reverted by EVM with USDC Interaction

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I've created a smart contract in Solidity that interacts with USDC. However, when I try to execute transactions, I'm encountering an EVM revert error. I'd appreciate some assistance in understanding what might be causing this.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IERC20 {
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract USDCInteraction {
    IERC20 public USDC = IERC20(0xD87Ba7A50B2E7E660f678A895E4B72E7CB4CCd9C);
   
    function approveUSDC(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
        return USDC.approve(spender, amount);
    }

    function transferUSDC(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
        return USDC.transfer(recipient, amount);
    }

    function transferFromUSDC(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
        return USDC.transferFrom(sender, recipient, amount);
    }

    function getAllowanceUSDC(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256) {
        return USDC.allowance(owner, spender);
    }
}
```

Here's the error message I'm seeing:

```
Transaction has been reverted by the EVM: 
{
  "blockHash": "0x3ba70ec628fa9d039f9e72d2afe2eea1f364abda33ce826f0ccaa4ffad8a486d",
  ...
  "status": false, 
  ...
  "type": "0x2", 
  "events": {}
}
```

Questions:

Are there any apparent issues with my contract that might cause this error?
Are there additional checks or modifications I should be aware of when interacting with USDC or similar tokens?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which `USDCInteraction` transaction is getting reverted?

Comment: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x644E879687F09A982B862351C09fBa56Be367c9D#code

this is the contract address you can check and try to transfer

Comment: I mean which function in your solidity code and how you are creating the transaction. Please add it to the question.

Comment: transferUSDC and transferFromUSDC function is not working I want to transfer USDC token to the contract

Comment: Also add to the question how you are calling these solidity functions

Comment: I am calling those functions from the eth scanner also with remix editor

Comment: Do you have any USDC in the wallet you used with remix editor?

Comment: Yes I have 216049585439 USDC

Answer (score 0):

```
"type": "0x2
```

this indicates a a "CREATE" transaction. Deploying a new contract is a `CREATE` transaction. I think that initialization address is not correct

```
IERC20 public USDC = IERC20(0xD87Ba7A50B2E7E660f678A895E4B72E7CB4CCd9C);
```

if the error was related to any function call, compiler will throw a proper error message because `ERC20` contracts have too many `require` checks in each function.

Comment: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xD87Ba7A50B2E7E660f678A895E4B72E7CB4CCd9C

This is the USDC coin on goerli and which is correct and https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x644E879687F09A982B862351C09fBa56Be367c9D#code

this is the contract address you can check if there is any issue with the code and the errors